# Custom theme is not showing success messages on product page

Tags: magento-2.1, product, messages, success-message

My other pages showing messages properly but not working on the product page. when I try to add to cart it does nothing. When I goto cart page it shows multiple time the success message. I tried by adding this to my `catalog_product_view` but no luck.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Is there any way I can access the session or cookie messages  programmatcially, so I can show them where I want? Thanks.

`Note:` I am using custom theme

Comment: there is a setting in the backen d that lets you display all blocks in the storefront. please verify that the messages block is rendered. If the block is not vissible you probably removed it somewhere in your layout xmls

Comment: Its shows `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages` this block but no message.You can check the url too for screenshot.http://prntscr.com/jrivp9